# Trailing edge dimmer to activate relay/contactor

Tags: relay, dimmer, contactor

I would like to take the 240V feed from a trailing edge dimmer that is driving LED lamps and use it also to activate a contactor or relay. This would in turn run a 230V fan.

(Reason: want to have a single dimmer switch controlling bathroom lights, but also have the switch turn the extractor fan on. But don't want to send a dimmed signal to the fan!)

I'm worried that the chopped signal from a trailing edge dimmer may not be what the coil of a relay or contactor needs.

Can anyone shed some light on this, please?

Either, will a relay work just fine on this circuit?
Or are some relays more tolerant of what activates them?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you get dimmers designed for 3-wire (switched-hot/dimmed-hot) magnetic fluorescent loads?

Comment: Do you have access to constant undimmed 230 V anywhere near your fan? If so, so can create a circuit from your dimmed output which would switch a relay from said 230 V to your fan.

Comment: Hi ThreePhaseEel, alas no. There have been a few dimmers in the past that offer essentially a two pole output, one dimmed, one switched, but they're hard to come by, and they were never produced with a trailing edge dimmer. The dimmer itself is the main event, and must take centre place. The dimming of LED lamps is so fussy!

Comment: Hi winny, yes, I do indeed have access to permanent live mains 230V. This is what I plan to use to drive the fan, switching it using the relay! I think what you've described is exactly what I'm trying to do! It's all about activating the relay with the dimmed output. Will the coil of the relay work okay with a dimmed/chopped output?

Comment: If you give a relay AC it will chatter. It would first have to be at least rectified and filtered, probably regulated too.

Comment: long shot given the age of this post, but how did you get on with this? I also want to control a relay with a trailing edge dimmer. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Phil, it's not that old, relatively! :-)

Comment: Hi Phil, it's not that old, relatively! :-) I tried a contractor which I thought might work, but it still chattered. I'm now pretty satisfied that the answer lies in automation. I have gone down the Hubitat route, and once there, there are almost limitless things one can do. For activation/trigger, there are a few options. Have a google for "Normally Open Current Sensing Switch Adjustable AC 0.2-30A SZC23-NO-AL-CH". I bought one from a Chinese shop of all things and just waited for it to arrive, about a tenner. Continues...

Comment: ...Pass one conductor from the light through it, and use it to trigger Zigbee (hacked!) Zigbee contact sensor or the like. This sends a signal into Hubitat, which can then then turn your fan on. It's possible that the switch above is, in fact, all you need, and it could just turn the fan on. Option two: use automation again, but get a smart dimmer. Lightwave RF products can do it, though the ecosystem is an absolute nightmare, and I couldn't in good faith recommend it. Varilight have just released a smart dimmer, the V-Pro Smart Supla. Continues...

Comment: ...This can be connected to a smart system like Alexa or Google Home, and from there you can go to Hubitat and turn your fan on. (It's possible that you cold do the whole thing in Alexa, in fact, but I like the Hubitat control and stability). The short answer is that I would skip straight to the above, as the direct control of a relay I could not make work. Hope that gives you some inspiration!